# AngularJS push element into existing json structure

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a service that is missing an element I require in my checkbox form - productUsed = false.

How can I push that into my json so it becomes part of the model for a form page for a series of checkboxes.

The json structure is similar to the below:

```
    "Data": [
    {
        "AcceptedValues": [
            {
                "Category": {
                    "Key": 2126,
                    "Value": "Category"
                },
                "ProfileOptions": [
                    {
                        "Key": 46546798,
                        "Value": "product Name"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": 46546769,
                        "Value": "product Name"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": 2164,
                        "Value": "product Name"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Category": {
                    "Key": 4646789,
                    "Value": "Category Name"
                },
                "ProfileOptions": [
                    {
                        "Key": 464987946,
                        "Value": "Product Name"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": 132465,
                        "Value": "Product Name"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to push it into the json instead of manipulating the object in angularjs?

Comment: once you save this data into a variable, you could manipulate it using bracket/dot syntax. provide more information on what exactly you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Mark: Hi, it doesnt have to be manipulating the JSON, I was attempting to have the JSON structure correct before I then attach it to my scope and render the form. That was on the basis that at some point in the future the service developer will incorporate the element I needed. If it can be done direct in angular then thats fine I will just have to remove that later when the service is ever updated to incorporate it.

Comment: @Nitsan - the json describes the of a form I am building - I have used NG-repeat to render out the form with checkboxes but currently theres no object to bind the checkboxes to.

Comment: Can you add some code for the service? Are you using the repository pattern to get data from a webapi?

Answer (score 0):

If the value is always false (at the moment) you can directly bind it in the view : `{{product.productUsed}}`.

If a property does not exists, Angular sets up a new property on the scope instead (default value is `false` i guess)

If the data is edited later, this code will works well.

Answer (score 0):

//let suppose the $scope.recordlist is the original json

```
$scope.UpdatedRecordlist = $scope.recordlist.map(function(obj) {
    return angular.extend(obj, {productUsed:'false'});
});
```

// Now $scope.UpdatedRecordlist is the new updated json with productUsed element